# Is there a way to run a python program using magic inside a loop in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python

I am using Jupyter Notebook on a Mac. I have a python program downloaded from github that takes an image and does transformations to it and returns the original and he transformed images. I am trying to use this program for a batch of images inside a folder.

This is what I have tried:

```
directory = r'/some/directory'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        !python /location/folder/imagemodifier.py -i ('/some/directory'+filename) -iter 50 -coeff 2 -n_comp 100
```

I get this error: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I have also tried:

```
directory = r'/some/directory'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    #only use images
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        imagetotransform = ('/location/folder/'+filename)
        !python /location/folder/imagemodifier.py -i imagetotransform -iter 10 -coeff 2 -n_comp 100
```

And I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

I also tried to make a function with it.

```
def imagefunction(image):
    !python /location/folder/imagemodifier.py -i image -iter 10 -coeff 2 -n_comp 100    

imagefunction("image.jpg")
```

and I get: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

So far the only way that it seems to work is if I only run the python program for one image and put its path there. Like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
!python /location/folder/imagemodifier.py -i 'image.jpg' -iter 500 -coeff 2 -n_comp 100
```

Comment: Change this ```-i ('/some/directory'+filename)``` to ```-i '/some/directory'+filename```

Comment: Still not working. I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

I tried printing the output of that program as:

```
directory = r'/some/directory'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    #only use images
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        print('/some/directory/'+filename)
```

And it prints

/some/directory/image10.jpg

without the ' at the beginning and end

Comment: Use only the 'filename' variable...

Comment: Nope, That was the first thing I tried

Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Please check on how that argument use is implemented in the python image processor.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and figured out it was easier just to modify the code in the py program.